# Access DateDiff in an If Statement

Tags: database, if-statement, report, ms-access-2007, datediff

I am working in Access 2007.  I am trying to do something and I think syntax is the issue but everything I'm trying isn't working.

I need a textbox in a report to give me the count of records that have aged more than 30 days, and another that's the same but 60 days.  So basically "If the record is more than 30 days past today, count it, or else don't."

The best thing I've done is this:

```
=Count(IIf(DateDiff("d",[StartDate],Date())>30,""))
```

[StartDate] is the date the record was put into the database, Date() is today I hope.

It returns a number, but the number is incorrect.  I've gotten DateDiff to work outside of an IF statement, so I think it's my syntax, but....what am I doing wrong?  Is there a much easier way to do this?  I have very limited knowledge of available functions and basically no VBA knowledge.

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Okay, this seems to work now...sorry I don't know what I was doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
=Sum(IIf(DateDiff("d",[StartDate],Date())>30, 1, 0))
```

Comment: This returns the same number.  I think because each record is 1 so the count and the sum would be the same

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you lmisunderstood the iff()

for instance iff(expression,action1,action2) means :

```
if expression=true then
  do action1
else
  do action2
end if
```

So what you're doing basically is counting what datediff returns and not  counting the records it matches!
 
Your approach would be correct if you had your count() in the first action of your iff().

I've got a better solution for you anyway...

Create the following function in your report (edit "MY_TABLE" to match your table's name:

```
Private Function MyCount(Optional intDays As Integer = 30) As Long

    MyCount = DCount("*", "MY_TABLE", "DateDiff('d', [StartDate], Date()) > " & intDays)

End Function
```

Then you just have to populate your textboxes as a follow

To get the last 30 days count:
    MyTextbox.value = MyCount

To get the last 60 days count:
    MyTextbox.value = MyCount(60)

Comment: Thanks Thomas, how do I create a function in a report?

Comment: Hey Thomas, actually what I wrote in the first place seems to be working now so I don't think I had COUNT in the wrong place.  I'd love to know what you're talking about with private functions and all but I'm getting the correct numbers right now